# Android systrace not showing my app's custom sections

Tags: android, performance, systrace

Trying to profile lags when scrolling in RecyclerView using systrace:

```
python systrace.py -o ~/tmp/newtrace.html -app=<my package>
```

But there is no entry for custom trace sections.
[image: No entry for my custom sections]

I'm tracing using following code

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    trace(sectionName = "GalleryDelegate.onCreateViewHolder") {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upload, parent, false)
        return ProfileMediaHolder(view, delegate)
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(items: List<ProfileDataEntry>, position: Int, holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
    trace(sectionName = "GalleryDelegate.onBindViewHolder") {
        val item = items[position] as ProfileDataEntry.MediaItem
        val castedHolder = holder as ProfileMediaHolder
        when (item) {
            is ProfileDataEntry.MediaItem.Item -> {
                castedHolder.bind(item.value)
            }
            is ProfileDataEntry.MediaItem.Placeholder -> {
                castedHolder.bind(item.type)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable systrace for your app using these commands

`adb shell "setprop debug.atrace.app_number 1"
 adb shell "setprop debug.atrace.app_0 appname"`

It is disabled by default. And for getting systrace, just specify your appname in command line like this.

`python systrace.py -t 4 -a appname -o mynewtrace.html perf sched gfx`

Comment: What can be the app name? Is it full package name like 'com.google.calendar'?

Comment: @XueQing yes. it's the name that you have in AndroidManifest.xml